# Java priority queues with skipped items reprocessed again first

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Let's say we have a `JobItem` which has two fields `jobId` and `dbTableName`.
We also have an Executor thread pool of 4.

Initally, the executor will run the first job item from the queue.
If the subsequent queue head have the same `dbTableName` say tableA, I want to get the next queue item next job item that doesn't have the same dbTableName and execute it first.

As the first job could take a long time, we could end up having processed multiple other job items with other tables before we processed tableA again

We want to make sure that all jobs for tableA are processed sequentially.

I have another List which keeps the list of current running jobs.

Currently, I see that only by iterating the queue items and checking the current running jobs list can provide such functionality.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: You could use a FIFO structure, and push back the job in your queue when a job is already running on a table with the same name

Answer (score 0):

For each table, you need a serial executor with separate input queue of jobs. Executor takes jobs from the queue and runs them sequentially.
Serial executor can be implemented in 2 ways: as a thread or as an actor. Thread implementation is simpler but requires more memory. Actor implementation requires additional dependency on a thread library. In your case, actor library can ba as simple as [SimpleActor.java](https://github.com/akaigoro/CodeSamples/blob/master/src/main/java/actor/simpleactor/SimpleActor.java).

Comment: Thanks for the idea of having separate input queues of jobs. It will be easier to implements using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

you can create thread pool and worker thread having queue.

```
public void execute(Runnable command) {

        final int key= command.getKey();
         //Some code to check if it is runing
        final int index = key != Integer.MIN_VALUE ? Math.abs(key) % size : 0;
        workers[index].execute(command);
    }
```

Worker code

```
 private final AtomicBoolean scheduled = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private final BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(maximumQueueSize);

    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        long timeout = 0;
        TimeUnit timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS;
        if (command instanceof TimeoutRunnable) {
            TimeoutRunnable timeoutRunnable = ((TimeoutRunnable) command);
            timeout = timeoutRunnable.getTimeout();
            timeUnit = timeoutRunnable.getTimeUnit();
        }

        boolean offered;
        try {
            if (timeout == 0) {
                offered = workQueue.offer(command);
            } else {
                offered = workQueue.offer(command, timeout, timeUnit);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RejectedExecutionException("Thread is interrupted while offering work");
        }

        if (!offered) {
            throw new RejectedExecutionException("Worker queue is full!");
        }

        schedule();
    }

    private void schedule() {
        //if it is already scheduled, we don't need to schedule it again.
        if (scheduled.get()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!workQueue.isEmpty() && scheduled.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            try {
                executor.execute(this);
            } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
                scheduled.set(false);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Runnable r;
            do {
                r = workQueue.poll();
                if (r != null) {
                    r.run();
                }
            }
            while (r != null);
        } finally {
            scheduled.set(false);
            schedule();
        }
    }
```